# Regex To Split String Into Sentences

Tags: java, regex, string

I need to split a string containing sentences such as:

```
"this is a sentence. this is another. Rawlings, G. stated foo and bar."
```

into

```
["this is a sentence.", "this is another.", "Rawlings, G. stated foo and bar."]
```

using regular expressions.

The other solutions I found split the third sentence into `"Rawlings, G."` and `"stated foo and bar."` which is not what I want.

Comment: check if previous char is not a capital letter

Comment: check \.\s{2} vs \.  Reason being that sentences end with 2 spaces after a period, but G. only has one space.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/BreakIterator.html#getSentenceInstance() Since Java 1.0

Comment: @Holger You should post this as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this

```
import java.text.BreakIterator;
import java.util.Locale;

public class StringSplit {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        BreakIterator iterator = BreakIterator.getSentenceInstance(Locale.US);
        String source = "This is a sentence. This is another. Rawlings, G. stated foo and bar.";
        iterator.setText(source);
        int start = iterator.first();
        for ( int end = iterator.next(); 
              end != BreakIterator.DONE; 
              start = end, end = iterator.next()) {
            System.out.println(source.substring(start, end));
        }
    }
}
```

out put is

```
This is a sentence.
This is another.
Rawlings, G. stated foo and bar.
```

Answer (score 6):

Regular expressions generally do not solve this problem.

You need a sentence detection algorithm, [OpenNLP](https://opennlp.apache.org/index.html) has one

It's simple enough to use:

```
String sentences[] = sentenceDetector.sentDetect(yourString);
```

And handles a lot of tricky cases

- "Walter White Jr. has money"
- "Mr. Pink does not give tips"

Comment: Before adding 3rd party library dependencies to your project, it’s always worth checking out [Java’s built-in capabilities](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/BreakIterator.html#getSentenceInstance())…

Comment: Fair enough, but you can't teach breakIterator how to handle some cases.

Answer (score 4):

Through nested lookbehinds.

Just split your input string according to the below regex. The below regex would split the input string according to the boundary which exists just after to a dot and also it check for the preceding character of dot. It splits only if the preceding character of dot is not an upppercase letter.

```
String s = "this is a sentence. this is another. Rawlings, G. stated foo and bar.";
String[] tok = s.split("(?<=(?<![A-Z])\\.)");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tok));
```

**Output:**

```
[this is a sentence.,  this is another.,  Rawlings, G. stated foo and bar.]
```

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=(?<![A-Z])\\.)`  Matches the boundary which exists just after to dot but the dot wouldn't be preceded by an uppercase letter.

Comment: Can you plz add one line of explanation. It will be helpful then

Comment: I suggest adding a space after `.` i.e. `"(?<=(?<![A-Z])\\. )"` otherwise it splits decimal numbers and domain names into two multiple sentences.